# Can Eclipse content assist filter by variable names?

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, content-assist

Is it possible to setup Eclipse to filter content assist suggestions by variable name?

**Use Case:**
Programming in Android and I use R.id.[Content-Assist]
There are some things defined that I would never like to be suggested; Particularly from libraries I'm using (Action Bar Sherlock). All ids are prefixed with "abs__" and it would be great if I could filter those out.

**So Far:**
Using *type filters* I am able filter based on package and inner class, but I would like to also filter by variable name.
Using something like

```
com.example.demo.R.id*
```

works to ignore the entire set of id's but I would like to only ignore the ones that start with a specific string like...

```
com.example.demo.R.id.abs__*
```

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. We'll have to see if anyone has any creative solutions. Otherwise this may have to become a Holiday project to build an eclipse plugin ontop of the content assist Hippiecomputation engine to do some filtering.